# on click buttons not working in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

for an app that I am creating, it doesn't allow me to specify what to do with the button and is giving me errors instead. The app helps switch between three music songs.

the code is down

```
    package com.example.atvan.babysleeper;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.atvan.babysleep.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button playBtn;
    Button one;
    Button two;
    Button three;
    SeekBar positionBar;
    SeekBar volumeBar;
    TextView elapsedTimeLabel;
    TextView remainingTimelabel;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    int totalTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        elapsedTimeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elapsedTimeLabel);
        remainingTimelabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remainingTimeLabel);
        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);


        //Media player

        public void setOne(View view){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music3);
        }
        public void setTwo(View view){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music2);
        }
        public void setThree(View view){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music1);

        }


        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.seekTo(0);
        mp.setVolume(0.5f,0.5f);
        totalTime = mp.getDuration();

        //position Bar
        positionBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.positionBar);
        positionBar.setMax(totalTime);
        positionBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        if (fromUser) {
                            mp.seekTo(progress);
                            positionBar.setProgress(progress);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }
                }
        );

        //Volume Bar
        volumeBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumeBar);
        volumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        float volumeNum = progress/100f;
                        mp.setVolume(volumeNum, volumeNum);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }
                }
        );

        //thread (update positionBar amd timeLabel)
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (mp != null) {
                    try{
                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.what = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                        handler.sendMessage(msg);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch (InterruptedException e){}
                }
            }
        }).start();



    }

    private Handler handler;

    {
        handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                int currentPosition = msg.what;
                // Update positionBar.
                positionBar.setProgress(currentPosition);

                // Update Labels.
                String elapsedTime = createTimeLabel(currentPosition);
                elapsedTimeLabel.setText(elapsedTime);

                String remainingTime = "- " + createTimeLabel(totalTime - currentPosition);
                remainingTimelabel.setText(remainingTime);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public String createTimeLabel(int time) {
        String timeLabel = "";
        int min = time / 1000 / 60;
        int sec = time /1000 % 60;

        timeLabel = min + ":";
        if (sec<10) timeLabel += "0";
        timeLabel += sec;

        return timeLabel;
    }

    public void playBtnClick(View view) {
        if (!mp.isPlaying()){
            //stopping
            mp.start();
            playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
        } else {
            //playing
            mp.pause();
            playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

        }
    }
```

the error it gives is that I have an illegal start of expression in my media player section. it also indicates to give ; somewhere there. when placed at the end of the code . it does not give any errors but the app doesn't run

the error is here

[image: the error]

[image]

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: well the error is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few logical errors here.  First you can not write method inside another method so remove the following lines of code from `onCreate()` and write it outside :

```
public void setOne(View view){ mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music3); } 
public void setTwo(View view){ mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music2); } 
public void setThree(View view){ mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music1); }
```

Second thing is you are initializing your `mediaPlayer` inside these methods, so what you should do it initially call 
`setOne()` method from `onCreate()` and call other methods after the currently playing song is over.

Please go through [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/) tutorial, though it shows "Building a media player in a service" but you can do it in your activity and the for you going through "**Step Three – Constructing the MediaPlayer**" is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just define functions in the middle of the function.  They need to be at class scope, outside of onCreate.

Comment: how would one do that?

Answer (score 0):

you have all the 3 methods defined inside onCreate(). Put them outside onCreate and call them from wherever you want. if by default you want setOne() then just call setOne() in onCreate().

//Media player

```
    public void setOne(View view){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music3);
    }
    public void setTwo(View view){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music2);
    }
    public void setThree(View view){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music1);

    }
```

something like

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    elapsedTimeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elapsedTimeLabel);
    remainingTimelabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remainingTimeLabel);
    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);

    //call setOne or setTwo or setThree based on what you want here.
```

Comment: the app crashes even then. it just doesn't open up. is this a problem with the structure or the code.

Comment: please post the crash.

Comment: u are using the instance of mp. so make sure you create the instance before you use them.

Comment: I posted the crash

Comment: but shouldn't it be based on the button so all three must need to work instead of calling one o0r the other

Comment: How are you loading the activities?

Comment: Yes , that method is called when u click on the button. So you need to call that method in onClick .But before that you need to define your default one if you are using t in in onCreate.

Comment: methods are not defined in onCreate.

Comment: one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               playOne(v);

            }
        });

Comment: what is playOne

Comment: sorry setOne();